# What does highest means when gradle handle dependency conflict?

Tags: java, gradle

I know that gradle choose the highest version when solve dependency conflict by default. But what's the definition of **highest**.

I have a dependency conflict problem and I run `dependencies` task finding that this two version of the same dependency conflicts: **AD-106715-1-SNAPSHOT** and **1.0.36**. Gradle choose the **1.0.36** version.

```
com.mycompany.service:ad-biz-jasper-contract:AD-106715-1-SNAPSHOT -> 1.0.36
```

But why? Is **1.0.36** higher than **AD-106715-1-SNAPSHOT**? But lexicographically the later one is higher.
So I want to know how gradle define which version is higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact rules are described in [the Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html#version_ordering), but the short (and somewhat oversimplified) version is:

1. split the version by `.`
2. compare each part numerically except if:

   - only one of the parts are numerical, then the numerical part is considered
     higher
   - both parts are non-numerical, then sort them  alphabetically, case-sensitive

Then there's a couple more rules with special cases for `dev`, `rc`, `final`, ... and what to do when one one string has more parts than the others and the first ones don't give a specific order, but those don't apply in this case.